# Including images, css files, etc in a WAR file each time on deployment?

Tags: java, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm starting to work on a java based web app, hosted on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. The problem is, the template of the app contains about 20-30 MB of assets (images, css files, javascript plugins, etc). I don't like the idea of having to deploy a new 30 MB war file each time I make a slight adjustment to my code. Plus, my connection's upload speed is not too great, so it would take me 5-10 mins for every simple upload.

Is there any other solution? Can I host the images / css on AWS somehow, separately from the rest of the app, so I won't have to include them in the war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the purpose of a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).  But you can just roll your own.  Host your assets somewhere else, make your html refer to those assets that are somewhere else.  But when you deploy, just deploy the dynamic content to AWS.

Comment: Any ideas how to do it on amazon specifically? I.e how to host files on it? I'd rather not run a new instance just for hosting files

Comment: Also, what would be a good way to include the url of the CDN in the code without having to hard-code it? In normal wars, you just do `src="/images"` and it works.

Comment: re: your first question, I'm not sure because I've never been in the same boat as yours, but my guess is that [s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is a better tool for this than AWS.  If I'm wrong, maybe you can just deploy your static assets to a different AWS server and leave them there.  You'll deploy your dynamic code way more often to a different server.

Comment: re: your second question, you have lots of options.  One is to use a variable everywhere like `src="${context}/images/"`.  This can be local when you're in "dev" mode and point to the CDN when in "prod" mode.

Comment: Thanks. Re {context}, where will it be set? I'm using Struts 2 as the framework if it helps.

Comment: You've got a lot of options for that.  You can put it in a database and read it form there.  You can put it in a ".properties" file that is different from your dev machine compared to your prod machine.  You could even compile the value in depending on how you build the code.

Answer (score 1):

If your using GIT for deployment it will do a diff. So only the changes are uploaded

Comment: you can't use git for java, only for other things e.g php.

Comment: btw do you happen to know if there's a way to get ram usage info?

Comment: I looked into a memory usage stat for instances a few months ago. It can be done but its allot of work to set it up.

Comment: If you're using the beanstalk-maven-plugin, Git is not only possible, but preferred. See [this url](http://docs.ingenieux.com.br/project/beanstalker/deploying-using-git.html) for more details.

Besides that, look for the cloudfront maven plugin